# How to debug celery delays and errors?

Tags: celery, mandrill

I am continuing Django project of someone who is using Celery along with Mandrill. There are daily reports which are sent to customers and due to some reason not a single mail is sent for three days, gets accumulated and sent together after three days. Since I am new to Celery, I want to know how to debug celery delays and errors, what are popular commands and execution path to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short tips:

- Set debug=True in celery config, it will take you register and execution time for every task.
- Install flower, popular  tool for monitoring tasks
- Use sentry for handy error tracking and aggregation

Happy debugging ;)